# Error importing redux:

Tags: node.js, redux, react-redux

ERROR:

> Error: Cannot find module 'redux'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
>     at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>     at Object. (C:\dev\Django 
>     code\portfolio_web\stats_frontend\node_modules\react- 
>     redux\lib\connect\mapDispatchToProps.js:8:14)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
>     at Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
>     at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\dev\Django 
>     code\portfolio_web\stats_frontend\node_modules\babel- 
>     register\lib\node.js:152:7)      at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)

---

The file where I import `react-redux` is `reduxStore.js`:

```
import {createStore} from 'react-redux; 
//There is nothing else. The function being imported doesn't change anything`
```

I'm running the file with babel-node, or with webpack-cli (which is using babel to transpile `ES2015`. In both cases I get the same error.

---

Tracing the error I can open the source (
`...\stats_frontend\node_modules\react-redux\lib\connect\mapDispatchToProps.js` of the error (its from official `react-redux` dist).

Line 8 (which causes the error) I can see a commonJS import: 
`var _redux = require('redux');`

Upon further inspection I can see that the node search algorithm will not find `'redux'` because no such file exists in `./node_modules/react-redux/` or in `./node_modules/`

---

I have installed and updated my `react-redux` installation with `node install --save-dev react-redux` with no errors.

I was hoping someone can provide insight on why the error occurs and how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing createStore from wrong library. import it from redux

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
```

Comment: Thanks. There's an additional issue that react-redux package hasn't installed its dependencies or even made note of them in package.json (namely redux). Opening an issue on github...

Comment: You have to install redux and react-redux individually

Comment: Is that intentional? redux installation is tiny and the docs don't mention anything about that.